# Showing an endemic steady state is stable

Tags: biology, steady-state, mathematical-biology

I need to show that the steady state of this non-dimensional model is stable using minimal algebra however I am not sure how to approach this without long lines of working.

The model is:

$$\frac{dS}{dt}=e-R_0SI-eS,\qquad
    \frac{dI}{dt}=R_0SI-I+\sigma R_0I(1-S-I)$$

and the endemic steady state is:

$$I=\frac{e}{2\sigma R_0}\left[\sqrt{\left(\frac{1-R_0\sigma}{e}+\sigma \right)^2+4(R_0-1)\frac{\sigma}{e}} -\left(\frac{1-R_0\sigma}{e}+\sigma \right) \right]$$

I understand that this can be shown by working through long lines of working however the question states explicitly it should not have lots of algebra. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For those of us who aren't biologist (but who do know something about differential equations) it would be useful to explain what **you** mean by endemic steady state. Emphasis is due to inconsistencies of terminology throughout science

Comment: If you just want stability, evaluate the Jacobian of the SI system at the endemic steady state.